# Group objects if multiple attributes are same in python

Tags: python

```
def class ObjClass:
    attr1;
    attr2;
    attr3;
    attr4;
    attr5;

    def __init__(self):
       print("Some logic goes here")
```

In another .py file

```
obj1 = obj.objClass();
obj1.attr1 = foo
obj1.attr2 = bar   (..... so on and so forth)

objList = []
objList.append(obj1)
objList.append(obj2)
objList.append(obj3)
objList.append(obj4)
objList.append(obj5)
```

Now all the objects that are there in this list, I want to group the ones that have the same attr1, attr2, attr3 but different attr4 and attr5. How do I do this?

What is the pythonic way of doing this. I know how to do this using lists but not using objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
def grouper(objs, attr_name):
    group =[]
    for obj in objs:
        if hasattr(obj, attr_name):
            group.append(obj)
    return group
```

Returns a list of objects- with the attribute you select equal to the value you want.

Comment: I want to group objects with same attributes. (not compare attribute to some value). Apologies if my earlier description was not clear. I have modified it.

Comment: Changed to use `hasttr` instead.  If you run this on all the attributes you are interested in you can do set addition and subtraction on the lists to find the set you are looking for.